# How to get secure flag cookies in JavaScript console?

Tags: javascript, cookies

I wanted to get all the cookies from the current page including secure flag cookies. I know you can disable secure flag but I need to find a way to disable it with JavaScript or get them with JavaScript. They're not included in `document.cookie`.

Answer (score 2):

You already *can* access cookies with the `secure` flag the same way you can access cookies without this flag. The only difference is, that cookies with the `secure` flag can't be accessed if you request a page via HTTP instead of HTTPS.

If you don't see them using `document.cookie` then you likely either didn't request the page via HTTPS, or the [`HttpOnly`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie#attributes) flag is also set. In both cases, it isn't possible to access these cookies through JavaScript. (Making them accessible anyway would somewhat defeat the purpose of those flags.)

(If the `HttpOnly` flag *is not* set and you *do* request the page via HTTPS, then the problem must be elsewhere, such as the current domain or path not matching the one specified on the cookie.)